# How to force query to return only first row from window?

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have data:

```
id | price | date
1  |    25 | 2019-01-01
2  |    35 | 2019-01-01
1  |    27 | 2019-02-01
2  |    37 | 2019-02-01
```

**Is it possible to write such query which will return only first row from window?** something like `LIMIT 1` but for the window `OVER( date )`?

I expect next result:

```
id | price | date
1  |    25 | 2019-01-01
1  |    27 | 2019-02-01
```

Or ignore whole window if first window row has `NULL`:

```
id | price | date
1  |  NULL | 2019-01-01
2  |    35 | 2019-01-01
1  |    27 | 2019-02-01
2  |    37 | 2019-02-01
```

result:

```
1  |    27 | 2019-02-01
```

Comment: Let us know your attempted query.

Comment: Look at the `distinct on (...)`: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-select-distinct/

Comment: @KaushikNayak: http://paste.scsys.co.uk/585140 this is the function

Comment: @horse added the right tag (  greatest-n-per-group) . Just click on it and you'll find several answers that will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order the rows by `date` and `id`, and take only the first row per `date`.
Then remove those where the price is NULL.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (date)
             id, price, date
      FROM mytable
      ORDER BY date, id
    ) AS q
WHERE price IS NOT NULL;
```

@Laurenz let me to provide a bit more explanation

```
select distinct on (<fldlist>) * from <table> order by <fldlist+>;
```

is equal to much more complex query:

```
select * from (
    select row_number() over (partition by <fldlist> order by <fldlist+>) as rn,*
    from <table>)
where rn = 1;
```

And here `<fldlist>` should be the beginning part (or equal) of `<fldlist+>`

Comment: Do not understand you query. Which price will be returned for `2019-01-01` date: `25` or `35`?

Comment: That world be 25. I'll add an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As `Myon` on IRC said:

> if you want to use a window function in WHERE, you need to put it into a subselect first

So the target query is:

```
select * from (
  select
    *
    agg_function( my_field ) OVER( PARTITION BY other_field ) as agg_field
  from sometable
) x
WHERE agg_field <condition>
```

In my case I have next query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, 
      FIRST_VALUE( p.price ) over( PARTITION BY crate.app_period ORDER BY st.DEPTH ) AS first_price,
      ROW_NUMBER() over( PARTITION BY crate.app_period ORDER BY st.DEPTH ) AS row_number
    FROM st 
    LEFT JOIN price p ON <COND>
    LEFT JOIN currency_rate crate ON <COND>
) p
WHERE p.row_number = 1 AND p.first_price IS NOT null
```

Here I select only first rows from the group and where `price IS NOT NULL`